# Finding $b$ such that $e^{5B_t - bt}$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

I have $X_t = e^{5B_t}$ and 
Where $B_t$ is brownian motion at time $t$.
$M_t = X_t \cdot e^{-bt}$

I need to find a value for $b$ such that $M_t$ is a martingale.

I am encountering difficulty, however.

$$\mathbb{E}[ e^{5B_t}e^{-bt} | \mathcal{F}_s] \space \text{for} \space s\leq t$$
$$= e^{-bt}\mathbb{E}[ e^{5B_t} | \mathcal{F}_s]$$ 
$$= e^{-bt}\mathbb{E}[ e^{5(B_t-B_s)+5B_s} | \mathcal{F}_s]$$ 
$$=exp\{\frac{25(t-s)}{2}+5B_s-bt\}$$

Now since $M_t$ is a martingale if $E[M_t | \mathcal{F}_s] = M_s$

We require that $$exp\{\frac{25(t-s)}{2}+5B_s-bt\} = exp\{5B_s-bs\}$$

Isn't this impossible to solve? Or have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you can get $b$ simply be computing the time zero expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}(e^{5B_t})= e^{0.5 \times 25 \times t}.$$
So $b = 12.5.$

With this value, your final equation 
$$\exp\{\frac{25(t-s)}{2}+5B_s-bt\} = \exp\{5B_s-bs\}$$
holds and we are done.

Comment: haha, interesting. I initially thought it was $b = 12.5$ as well, but for some reason ruled that option out when I got $$\text{exp}\{12.5s + 5B_s\}$$ 

No idea why! -_-

Thanks though.

Curious what you mean by computing the expectation at time 0, and why that would actually work? 

Why is $\mathbb{E}(e^{5B_t}) = e^{0.5 \cdot 25 \cdot t}$ ?

Comment: this is a very standard result for log-normals. It plays a very big role in quant finance so just about any book on financial maths.

Comment: thanks mark, I will read into i further.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t,x)$ be the function defined by $f(t,x) = e^{5x - bt}$. We observe that $\partial_t f(t,x) = -b f(t,x)$ and $\partial_x^2 f(t,x) = 25 f(t,x)$. For $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ to be a local martingale, we require that $\partial_t f(t,x) = -\frac{1}{2} \partial_x^2 f(t,x)$. This tell us that for $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ to be a local martingale, we require that $b = \frac{25}{2}$. Let us check whether this value of $b$ also gives us that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale. To this end, we need to check that for all $T> 0$, $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T \left| \partial_x f(t,x) \right|^2 dt \right) < \infty.$$ So observe that \begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T \left| \partial_x f(t,x) \right|^2 dt \right) &=& 25 \int_0^T \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left( - \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \exp \left( 5x - \frac{25}{2} t \right) dx dt \\
&=& \frac{25}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \exp \left( - \frac{25}{2}t \right) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left( 5x - \frac{1}{2} x^2 \right) dx dt \\
&=& 25 e^{\frac{25}{2}} \int_0^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \exp \left( - \frac{25}{2} t \right) dt < \infty. 
\end{eqnarray*} Therefore $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ defines a martingale.